# UITableView separator line not closed

Tags: uitableview, line, separator

all

I am doing some jobs using UITableView, But I don't know how to make the UITableView's separator line closed, some blank in front of the cell.

In other words, the line width is not the whole screen width, Is this new feature in iOS7 or iOS8? How can I set the separator line closed, like customized table cell.

I tried the UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine, not any effect.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a default ui. If you want a separator line with full width, just add 1 pixel ui to the bottom of your custom cell.

Comment: @HMHero OK, Thanks a lot. BTW, Do u know how can I make the cell click effect, such as change the cell background color or something else?

Comment: @Mark selectionStyle?

Comment: @HMHero Yeah, I set the selection style as UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone, I know this will make no effect when click the table cell, I just want to make a simple customize effect, e.g. when click the cell, the background change from light gray to dark gray.

Comment: @Mark use UIView animateWithDuration - and change background color? You can achieve it in many different ways.

Comment: @HMHero OK, Thanks, I will try more.

Comment: Maybe the best choice is customizing a UITableViewCell and draw a line according to requirement. Then set the UITableViewCell separator line style to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone. .